# I'm looking for a "date-picker" that works for all the browsers

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, mojolicious

This is how it should look on all the browsers:
[image]

And this is how it looks on Safari, for example:
[image]

This is the code that I am using at the moment:

```
<%= date_field 'birth_date', rel => 'birth_date',
        class => "form-control", required => undef %>
```

Comment: A date picker can be useful for selecting dates within a month or two of "today", but is seldom a good match for a Date of Birth field.  I created the [jQuery date text entry](http://grantm.github.io/jquery-datetextentry/) plugin for this type of field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the [Mojolicious `date_field` tag helper](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Plugin/TagHelpers#date_field). This generates a `<input type="date">` HTML input field.

But [support for the date input isn't universal](https://caniuse.com/input-datetime). In particular, you'll see that Safari doesn't support it.

So you'll need to use some kind of plugin, I guess. If you're using jQuery, then [one of these](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-date-time-picker.html) might work for you.